# Blazor server and async

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

quick question:

Let's say we have two Buttons, both click events call async handlers where I do whatever, but it's important to note that they might do multiple awaits. And they are manipulating the same object, which needs to be refreshed on the UI (orher fields).

Now the user clicks button1 and then button2. How can I make sure the entire code of button1 is executed before the execution of button2 starts?

Notes:

- I dont want to disable the second button during the work of the first one
- I probably can't use non async code, because we are doing (slow) IOs, and we don't want to block the entire thread (The thread might be shared between multiple blazor sessions, right? Because one blazor tab/windows doesnt spawn a dedicated thread, right?)

Some ideas I had:

- Use semaphore.WaitAsync, but the problem is that we don't know which await will be the next in the queue, no order is guaranteed
- Use lock?
- Spawn my own thread and use non async code, plus make sure only one thread is executed at the same time

The guaranteed order is important (started by the user action), so it doesn't matter if the user clicks button2 before button1, it must always be executed in the order the user clicked a button, where both code executions do multiple awaits.

Thanks

**update: lets do the exercise with three buttons, since its important that the order is exactly the one the user clicked the buttons. While the button count/input events can vary.**

I found that: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncLock.md
Keep the order too! Awesome

Comment: Use a synchronous handler to add  items to a queue to track the requests, and at the end of each request handler, call itself if there's still another request left in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything exotic.  You just need to disassociate the Task that represents the work from the event that triggers it.

Here's a Index single page that demonstrates how to do it.

I've added disabling the button while its `Task` is running.  I assume you don't want to start multiple copies of the same task.

First a TaskManager to manage the running tasks.

```cs
public class TaskManager
{
    private Dictionary<Guid, Task> _tasks = new();

    public void AddTask(Guid taskUid, Task task)
    {
        if (!_tasks.ContainsKey(taskUid))
            _tasks.Add(taskUid, task);

        this.ClearCompletedTasks();
    }

    public Task GetAwaiter(Guid taskUid)
    {
        this.ClearCompletedTasks();
        var tasks = _tasks.Where(task => task.Key != taskUid).Select(task => task.Value).AsEnumerable();
        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public void ClearCompletedTasks()
    {
        var tasks = _tasks.Where(task => task.Value.IsCompleted).ToList();
        tasks.ForEach(task => _tasks.Remove(task.Key));
    }
}
```

And then the demo page with six tasks.

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Executing Sequential Async Methods</h1>

<div class="p-2">
    <button disabled="@_button1Disabled" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.Button1Clicked>Execute Async Task 1</button>
    <button disabled="@_button2Disabled" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.Button2Clicked> Execute Async Task 2</button>
    <button disabled="@_button3Disabled" class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.Button3Clicked> Execute Async Task 3</button>
    <button disabled="@_button4Disabled" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.Button4Clicked>Execute Async Task 4</button>
    <button disabled="@_button5Disabled" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.Button5Clicked> Execute Async Task 5</button>
    <button disabled="@_button6Disabled" class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.Button6Clicked> Execute Async Task 6</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    <pre>
        @_log.ToString()
    </pre>
</div>

@code {
    private System.Text.StringBuilder _log = new();

    private readonly TaskManager _taskManager = new();
    private bool _button1Disabled;
    private bool _button2Disabled;
    private bool _button3Disabled;
    private bool _button4Disabled;
    private bool _button5Disabled;
    private bool _button6Disabled;

    private async Task Button1Clicked()
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        _button1Disabled = true;
        var task = ButtonWork(uid, "1");
        _taskManager.AddTask(uid, task);
        await task;
        _button1Disabled = false;
    }

    private async Task Button2Clicked()
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        _button2Disabled = true;
        var task = ButtonWork(uid, "2");
        _taskManager.AddTask(uid, task);
        await task;
        _button2Disabled = false;
    }

    private async Task Button3Clicked()
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        _button3Disabled = true;
        var task = ButtonWork(uid, "3");
        _taskManager.AddTask(uid, task);
        await task;
        _button3Disabled = false;
    }

    private async Task Button4Clicked()
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        _button4Disabled = true;
        var task = ButtonWork(uid, "4");
        _taskManager.AddTask(uid, task);
        await task;
        _button4Disabled = false;
    }

    private async Task Button5Clicked()
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        _button5Disabled = true;
        var task = ButtonWork(uid, "5");
        _taskManager.AddTask(uid, task);
        await task;
        _button5Disabled = false;
    }

    private async Task Button6Clicked()
    {
        var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        _button6Disabled = true;
        var task = ButtonWork(uid, "6");
        _taskManager.AddTask(uid, task);
        await task;
        _button6Disabled = false;
    }

    private async Task ButtonWork(Guid uid, string name)
    {
        var task = _taskManager.GetAwaiter(uid);
        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            _log.AppendLine($"Button {name} work awaiting tasks to complete");
            await task;
        }
        _log.AppendLine($"Button {name} work started");
        // We need to Update the UI
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        _log.AppendLine($"Button {name} work done");
        // We need to Update the UI
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Here's a link to an interesting MS docs article on the subject of Async scheduling and how to make a hot breakfast - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/

Comment: Quote: I dont want to disable the second button during the work of the first one. Update: sorry forget it

Comment: @DennyWeinberg - NP - you had the humility to leave the comment rather than delete it :-)

Comment: You've moved the goalposts.  See my revised answer.  Stephen is an authority on Async in MS code.

Comment: Yeah that AsyncLock seems to do the trick, as it keep the "waiting" order too!

Comment: Are you referring to Stephen's `AsyncLock`? You don't need it.  The code above works without it.

Comment: Yes, but my 3 button use case was only to demonstrate my issue. In reality its much much more complicated.

Comment: It always is.  [Don't take the wrong way ;-)]  Questioners asks a question, get an answer and then say "It's not quite than simple", what I really meant to say was .....  I've updated my answer to show how you can use a TaskManager class to manage multiple running tasks.  Anyway, if you now have the knowledge to solve your issue, then problem solved.

Comment: You are right. I will accept your answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Oh wait, the execution order is not guaranteed, when multiple buttons are waiting... no?

Comment: I think it is.  The Task will start, but then await any other Tasks that were in the queue when it started `var task = _taskManager.GetAwaiter(uid);`, gets a Task awaiting the Tasks in the queue when it made it's request for the awaiter.  These are the tasks for previous button clicks.  I tested it quickly and it looked ok.  You'll need to add some logging in your live setup and make sure it does.